# How can I split a text file with # as separator and then split the lines inside the separated part?

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

I have a text file that have a pattern like

```
#
a,b
c,d
#
e,f
g,h
```

I want the result to print as each block separated is an element and each line in the block is a sub-element to the block one

`[[[a, b], [c, d]], [[e, f], [g, h]]]`

Here is my code, any suggestion from here to get the result ? Thanks

```
    ret_list = []

    a = open(file_name,'r')
    content = a.read()
    content = content.split('#')
    for l in content:
        l = l.strip().split('\n')
        for elem in l:
            temp = []
            elem = elem.split(',')
            if '' not in elem:
                temp.append(elem)
            ret_list.append(temp)
    
    a.close()
```

And the result I got

```
[[], [['a', 'b']], [['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f']], [['g', 'h']]]
```

Comment: What is the difference between what this code actually does and what you want it to do?

Comment: Well my idea was first split the part separated by # first, then split the lines in those parts. However I'm struggling to get the lines in the same part returned as in one list, resulting my code to have two sublists instead of two elements in one [[a, b]], [[c,d]] instead of [ [a, b], [c,d] ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating `temp = []` for every line - but you want to create it for every "block" - so you move it outside of the inner for loop. (same for the `ret_list.append()`)

```
content = content.split('#')
for l in content:
    l = l.strip().split('\n')
    temp = []
    for elem in l:
        elem = elem.split(',')
        if '' not in elem:
            temp.append(elem)
    ret_list.append(temp)
```

This gives you

```
[[], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]]
```

You could add a check that `temp` is not empty before appending.

```
if temp:
    ret_list.append(temp)
```

Another way to avoid the leading empty "block" is to strip before splitting

```
content.strip('#').split('#')
```

Finally, this is how I would write it.

```
ret_list = []

for block in content.strip('#').split('#'):
    lines = block.strip().splitlines()
    lines = [ line.split(',') for line in lines ]
    ret_list.append(lines)
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, I have just figured out the temp = [ ] goes back to empty after every line loop. However your final suggestion is much better, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in content:
    l = l.strip().split('\n')
    k=[]
    for elem in l:
        temp=[]
        elem = elem.split(',')
        if '' not in elem:
            temp.append(elem)
            k=k+temp
    if k!=[]:
        ret_list.append (k)
print (ret_list)
```

i created new list k to store a block with two block i.e `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` and then added to ret_list if k list is not empty

output

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have just solved the problem and it does not lie on the k but it because the temp list declaration should be outside of the second loop so it can contain two elements to add in the result list before refreshing itself back to [ ]. 
However, appreciated your help